# Broken Words Cryptic #1

Tags: word, wordplay

This game can be also played here: https://www.brainzilla.com/word-games/broken-words/cryptic/1/

Use the following chunks to create words related to a specific theme. The theme name itself is also hidden within those words.

<kbd>QUO</kbd> - <kbd>EAN</kbd> - <kbd>SKY</kbd> - <kbd>PAS</kbd> - <kbd>IBB</kbd> - <kbd>TUR</kbd> - <kbd>OFB</kbd> - <kbd>DOD</kbd> - <kbd>LUE</kbd> - <kbd>DER</kbd> - <kbd>TEL</kbd> - <kbd>ISE</kbd> - <kbd>POW</kbd> - <kbd>SHA</kbd> - <kbd>GER</kbd> - <kbd>CAR</kbd> - <kbd>DES</kbd> - <kbd>COB</kbd> - <kbd>ALT</kbd>

Theme: ?

- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?

All the answers have a multiple of three letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Shades of Blue**
>  Pastel Turquoise Sky Caribbean Cobalt Powder Dodger

Answer (score 5):

The message is

> Shades Of Blue

Answers:

> Sky,  Caribbean, Turquoise, Pastel, Dodger, Cobalt, Powder